# Getting random "Connection is read-only" - Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I've spent the last couple of days debugging some really strange errors.

I have an exposed WebService which calls a service-metod called "addNewOrder"
This service-method is annotated with 
`@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`

This service-method will need to read and write to the database.

I would think that the annotation above would ensure that every time this method is called, i'm getting a new transaction that can do what is needed.

But about 50% of the time, when "addNewOrder" is called, i get these strange errors:

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:143 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1009
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:144 - Connection is read-only. Queries leading to data modification are not allowed
```

Does anyone have any clue as to why this might happen? And why is it random?

Im using Spring 3.2.4, Hibernate 4.1.7, Mysql-connector 5.1.26

This is my applicationContext snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="no.aida.model"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="${jpa.show.sql}"/>
            <property name="generateDdl" value="${jpa.generate.ddl}"/>
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="${jpa.dialect}"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean id="jpaDialect" class="no.aida.dao.hibernate.IsolationSupportHibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- javax.sql.DataSource supplied by Jakarta Commons Connection Pooling -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${mysql.db.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${mysql.db.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${mysql.db.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${mysql.db.password}"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="3" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="30" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<!-- Enable @Transactional support -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: Well i'll be damned. Just a few mins after posting this i finally found the error. The reason it is random is because I have another service-method called "getStatus" which is annotated by read-only. And if this is called then every request using the same connection will also be read-only. But i still cant understand why the read-only is not re-set when the connection is used on a method annotated with readOnly = false...

Comment: And to add to the saga. The reason why the connections was not reset, was because we had implemented a custom JpaDialect that had forgotten to reset the connections... doooooh!

Answer (score 2):

Well i'll be damned. Just a few mins after posting this i finally found the error. The reason it is random is because I have another service-method called "getStatus" which is annotated by read-only. And if this is called then every request using the same connection will also be read-only. But i still cant understand why the read-only is not re-set when the connection is used on a method annotated with readOnly = false...

And to add to the saga. The reason why the connections was not reset, was because we had implemented a custom JpaDialect that had forgotten to reset the connections... doooooh!

Answer (score -1):

```
value="${mysql.db.url}"
```

Could you please specify the connect url? Do you use:

```
failOverReadOnly=false
```

or not? This should help.

BR, Ilya